# Execution time each time displays different time for same operation in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I build the program in c# . i want to find the time taken by the operation. the  code is working but every time it display the different output for the same input. how can it solve it??

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
```

my code

```
sw.Stop();
Double timeTaken = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
Label.Text = timeTaken.ToString();
```

Comment: you want to get execution time, you get it...yes it is different for each execution, what is the question??

Comment: Your computer is doing a lot of work, not just running your code, so you can never expect it to take the exact same amount of time every single time

Comment: How different? Things are unlikely to take precisely the same amount of time every time you do them.

Comment: You can't. It depends..

Comment: Enable trace and use Trace.Write, that will help you find exact time.

Answer (score 0):

Is your question why `timeTaken` is not the same every time?  That's to be expected:  for all kinds of reasons, different runs of the operation may take different amounts of time.

Also, note this:

> By default, the elapsed time value of a Stopwatch instance equals the
>   total of all measured time intervals. Each call to Start begins
>   counting at the cumulative elapsed time; each call to Stop ends the
>   current interval measurement and freezes the cumulative elapsed time
>   value. Use the Reset method to clear the cumulative elapsed time in an
>   existing Stopwatch instance.

So if your Elapsed time keeps getting bigger, you may need to execute a `Reset`.

That's from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to expect something to take precisely the same amount of time each time you do it. It is traditional to measure something several times and report the average, possibly along with the variance.

A variety of things affect the time taken - other programmes running, network traffic, cached file reads, etc etc.